# Formal Phrase for 'cancel out'

Tags: terminology

For example, in a simple equation: xy = yz, the unknown y can be 'cancelled out'. What would be a more formal phrased with the meaning of 'cancel out'?

Comment: "Cancellation" is already a formal phrase.

Comment: $y$ can only be cancelled out when $y \neq 0$

Comment: "We may divide both terms of the equality be the common factor y resulting in the reduced equality x = z".  But as john doe points out, you can only do that if you know for certain $y\ne 0$ and as Parcly Taxel points out "cancellation" or "cancellation of common factors" is perfectly valid and acceptable and formal.

Comment: @johndoe Thank you, but sorry for not explaining the physics context where the unknown being cancelled is a mass and therefore a non-zero value.